# Get related field m2m django though

Tags: python, django, has-many-through, m2m

Hi I'm new in Django and I'm not getting the related object in the through model.

My code:

```
#models.py
class Candidate(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, primary_key=True)
    birth = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    ...

class Job(models.Model):
    candidate = models.ManyToManyField('Candidate', through='CandidateToJob')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    ...

class CandidateToJob(models.Model):
    job = models.ForeignKey(Job, related_name='applied_to')
    candidate = models.ForeignKey(Candidate, related_name='from_user')
    STATUS_CHOICES = (
       ('1', 'Not approved'),
       ('2', 'Approved'),
       ('3', 'Hired')
    )
    status = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=STATUS_CHOICES)
```

In the views I have

```
#views.py
class Screening(generic.DetailView):
    model = Job
    template_name = 'dashboard/screening.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
         context = super(Screening, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
         context['candidate_list'] = self.object.candidate.select_related().annotate
         return context
```

The template I have:

```
 #url.py
 url(r'^dashboard/job/(?P<pk>\d+)/screening/$', views.Screening.as_view(), name='screening'),

 #HTML
 {% for candidate in candidate_list %}

     {{ candidate.user.get_full_name }} #this works 

     {% for candidatetojob in job.candidatetojob_set.all %}
          {{ candidatetojob.get_status_display }} 
     {% endfor %}

 {% endfor %}
```

The thing is I am not being able to get the status related to the candidate to the specific job.
How can I get it?

And what is the best way to update this status without reload the entire page?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you want to access the model instance in your template - the default name which DetailView provides is `object`. So instead `job.candidatetojob_set.all` try `object.candidatetojob_set.all`

Comment: And best way to update status without reload the entire page - use AJAX (send updated data and object pk to some view and save it there)

Comment: Thanks. Can you provide some example of how to acomplish the ajax update?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/#ajax-example but in your case inherit `UpdateView` not `CreateView`

Comment: Thanks again. I have tried object.candidatetojob_set.all but it didn't work.

Comment: The error I'm getting: type object 'Job' has no attribute 'candidatetojob_set'

Comment: because you have changed default `related_name` to `applied_to`

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I could retrieve the candidate status by using:

```
 {% for candidate in object.applied_to.all %}
     {{ candidate.get_status_display }}
 {% endfor %}
```